# Can access asp.net pages and wcf services remotely, though not locally

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

We've deployed an asp.net site and WCF services in IIS, and can access the site and services remotely with no issues. We have site bindings set up in order that for remote calls we're using https, and we use the URL Rewrite IIS add-in to redirect requests to https if they are http requests. All requests are working remotely, however when we actually log onto the Windows 2008 Server, open up IIS 7.5 and try to browse the content locally on the server we get a credential challenge Title: "Windows Security" Message: "Connecting to {server name}" with ok/cancel buttons.

I'm logged into the server with the same credentials that I'm accessing the web site on from my local machine.

Any ideas?

The error message that come is as below:

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'.
The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM,Negotiate'.
```

As mentioned this error does not come when the service is accessed remotely. This only happens while calling the service from the server where it is hosted. Probably some setting in IIS?

Comment: Are you trying http:/ / localhost/... , http:/ / ServerName/... or the external web address? Do you get the same behavior for all 3 of these approaches? Both with http and https?

Comment: For http localhost following is the error message 
There was no endpoint listening at <<service>> that could accept the message. This is often caused by an inco rrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. 

For https localhost the error message is as follows
Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'localhost'.

Comment: We've restricted the service to only https uring Url Rewrite add-in module in IIS, so to answer the question:
- Using external web address - We get prompted for credentials.
- Using localhost - get certification error, we can continue and view the service then.
- Using server name - get certification error, we can continue and view the service then.

Comment: Also one other peice of information, if we run code on the web server itself that connects to the WCF service hosted on the same machine and execute a service method, it works using https://{servername}, but doesn't work using https://{externaladdress} or https://{localhost}.

Answer (score 0):

As the Exception says, the authentication schemes do not match. Your client does not offer NTLM. Please check the internet explorer enhanced security configuration and see if it is active or see if it is restricted otherwise to use NTLM.